# How can I pass the old value of a Bootstrap-Vue input to a method it calls?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using v-for to create a large number of inputs. These inputs will become the *keys* of an object, so I can't(?) use v-model to directly link the inputs to the object. The app user will also be able to add and delete keys, so only the object itself is a global value. Instead, I'm doing this:

```
<b-form-group horizontal label-cols="1" v-for="(site, a) in config.sites">
    <b-form-group horizontal label-cols="1" label="Site: ">
        <b-form-input type="text" :value="a" @change="changeKey" required />
    </b-form-group>
</b-form-group>
```

changeKey is a method that requires the old key (this method of changing the key of an object being cribbed from elsewhere on this site):

```
changeKey: function(old_key, new_key) {
    Object.defineProperty(this.config, new_key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.config, old_key));
    delete this.config[old_key];
}
```

I know that I can pass only the old value with

```
<b-form-input type="text" :value="a" @change="changeKey(a)" required />
```

and only the new value with

```
<b-form-input type="text" v-model="a" @change="changeKey(a)" required />
```

However, I need *both* the old and new values. I can't seem to pass the event object, which is the solution proposed by other answers to similar questions:

```
@change="changeKey(a, $event)"
```

`$event` and `event` aren't recognized as variables.
How can I access both the old and new values from my method? (Alternative methods of changing the keys of objects dynamically assigned to Vue components would also be helpful, but off-topic.)

Comment: why you could not use `v-model` directive? i see that you could

Comment: I experienced errors using `v-model` for this variable because it is the key of an object (and there are nested inputs under it to modify its values). The purpose of the changeKey method is to copy the values to a new key and delete the old key when the key is changed in the UI. I cannot change the structure of the base object (i.e. make this value not an object key) because it is taken as an input to an entirely different program.

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: I did. Your proposal of `config.sites[a]` shows the incorrect value (this is equivalent to `site`): my intended displayed/editable value is `a`. E.g. if `config.sites = {A: "abc"}` I need the input to be linked to `A`, not `abc`.

Comment: so try `v-for="(site, a,index) in config.sites">` and `v-model="config.sites[a]"`

Comment: Again, the input must be `v-model="a"` if `v-model` is used.

Comment: could you provide a running code in codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: [This](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/omVwmm) demonstrates the structure of the object and the datasource of the input field. However, since the site doesn't recognize the Bootstrap components I'm using, I've stripped it back to vanilla HTML and the functionality is no longer the same.

Comment: you could use bootstrap vue to in this example https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/oEmzQr

Comment: [There](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqExwM) you go. The problem is exactly the same as far as I can tell, unless the functionality is blocked by Bootstrap.